# Display upload and download speed values of the device in UWP application[Windows 10 anniversary edition(10.0;Build 14393) ](vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, uwp, desktop-bridge

With reference to the link https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/ I tried the following methodology. However, I am getting errors. The steps followed are as follows:

Development Environment: Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017,Version 15.9.23 enter code here

1.Created a console application(c#) that calls an external non visual studio internet speed calculation exe and retrieved the download and upload values and assigned them to ValueSet variables.
Also added ‘AppServiceConnection’ to send the results to UWP based on request from UWP.

```
  static AppServiceConnection connection = null;
           connection = new AppServiceConnection();
           connection.AppServiceName = "xyz";            
           connection.PackageFamilyName = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.FamilyName;
                connection.RequestReceived += Connection_RequestReceived;
    AppServiceConnectionStatus status = await connection.OpenAsync();

private static void Connection_RequestReceived(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceRequestReceivedEventArgs args)
       {
            
//added code to call the external exe file
                    

ValueSet valueSet = new ValueSet();               
valueSet.Add("Upload", upload);
valueSet.Add("Download", download);              
args.Request.SendResponseAsync(valueSet).Completed += delegate { };

}
```

Note: • Set the output type of the Console Application to -> Properties->Application->outputtype -> WindowsApplication • Target Framework of Console Application : .NET Framework 4.6.1

2. Created a UWP application
   • Added reference to Windows Desktop Extension for UWP. • Added code in Page.xaml.vb (UWP) :On click of Listview link “Calculate Internet Speed”

If(ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract", 1, 0)) Then Await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync("Background") End If

• Added following code in App.xaml.vb (UWP)

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnBackgroundActivated(ByVal args As BackgroundActivatedEventArgs)

            MyBase.OnBackgroundActivated(args)
            Dim taskInstance As IBackgroundTaskInstance = args.TaskInstance
        Dim AppService As AppServiceTriggerDetails = TryCast(taskInstance.TriggerDetails, AppServiceTriggerDetails)
       
 _appServiceDeferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral()
            AddHandler taskInstance.Canceled, AddressOf OnAppServicesCanceled
            AddHandler _appServiceConnection.RequestReceived, AddressOf OnAppServiceRequestReceived
         AddHandler _appServiceConnection.ServiceClosed, AddressOf AppServiceConnection_ServiceClosed

            _appServiceConnection = AppService.AppServiceConnection

    End Sub

Private Sub OnAppServiceRequestReceived(ByVal sender As AppServiceConnection, ByVal args As AppServiceRequestReceivedEventArgs)

        Dim messageDeferral As AppServiceDeferral = args.GetDeferral()
        Dim Upload As String = args.Request.Message("Upload").ToString()
        Dim Download As String = args.Request.Message("Download").ToString()        
 messageDeferral.Complete()         


 End Sub
```

3)Created a UWP Package:                                                                                     • Applications :Added Console Application( Output type as Windows Application) and UWP application • Package.appmanifest:

• Set the UWP application as Entry Point

Configuration : • UWP package- ‘Deploy’ • UWP application and UWP package – ‘x86’ platform After build, I get the following issues:

1. .pdb files not loaded
2. Networkinformationfactory.cpp not found
3. On reaching this part of code,

Await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync("Background")
The following error shows up

4. ‘.WinTypes.pdb not loaded’

Comment: I found you pass the parameter to desktop extension, Please check this [blog](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-2/), and if the problem is still exist please provide me code sample for testing.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT . I have implemented background processing code from that blog. The description of the github code says this code is valid for Windows 10 build 16299 or later.  I have Windows 10 build 14393. Will this code not run in my version of code?

Comment: Yep, please try to update the target version to 16299 to exclude this.

Comment: Its an existing UWP application and it cannot be upgraded currently . I was trying to add this new feature of displaying the internet speed value based on user request.

Comment: I'm you can't implement this without updating the target version to 16299.